# How can I delete special characters inside a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

So let's say I have an array like this, what would be the most effiecient way to go through the array and erase all the '$' signs?

I have tried many different approaches but none of them seem to work properly, any thoughts?

```
const myArray = [
        ['$','H','e','$','$','l'],
        ['l','$','o','$','W','o'],
        ['r','l','$','d','$','M'],
        ['y','$','N','a','$','m'],
        ['e','$','i','s','$','p'],
        ['a','b','$','l','$','$'],
        ['$','o','$','$','w','$']
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const myArray = [
    ['$','H','e','$','$','l'],
    ['l','$','o','$','W','o'],
    ['r','l','$','d','$','M'],
    ['y','$','N','a','$','m'],
    ['e','$','i','s','$','p'],
    ['a','b','$','l','$','$'],
    ['$','o','$','$','w','$']
];

const result = myArray.map(arr => arr.filter(letter => letter != '$'));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested for loop will work very quickly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++){
      if (myArray[i][j]=='$')
          myArray[i][j]==''
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as well but it won't delete the index, it will only replace '$' with a space, but it's a simple and quick way

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter the individual Arrays in myArray like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].filter(x => x != '$');
}
```